# type error in python: list indeces must be int or float not str

Tags: python, json, python-requests

```
import requests

import json

url=("http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=ac871f6d1b7b4f46bd71d9c4df281f12")

news=requests.get(url=url,data="hello").text

news_dict=json.loads(news)

arts=news_dict["articles"]["title"]

print(arts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough info to answer but I guess
arts=news_dict[0]["articles"]["title"] might work.

Can you print news_dict if above doesn't work?

Edit: I was from smart phone. now checked what news_dict is,

as others answered already. it is a list of dictionary,

You can see all titles by

```
for i in news_dict["articles"]:
    print(i["title"],"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

`news_dict['articles']` returns a list of dictionaries. So to get all article titles, do:

```
[article_dict['title'] for article_dict in news_dict["articles"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that news_dict["articles"] is a list of returned articles. To get each articles title you need to iterate trough them.

```py
arts = [article['title'] for article in news_dict["articles"]]

print(arts)
```